# Es posible recorrer un JSON con ciclo for? (no usar foreach)

Tags: php, json

Tengo un JSON que es facil recorrer con un foreach, la estrucrura del JSON es la siguiente:

```
{
 "llave":"valor","llave":"valor","llave":"valor"
}

foreach ($arrayJson as $key => $value) {
    echo $key . ': ' . $val;
}
```

Quisiera saber si hay una forma de extraer los llaves y los valores con un ciclo for en PHP.

Comment: ¿Podrías indicar el motivo por el cual no quieres usar `foreach`?

Comment: Puedes modificar el JSON de salida en un arreglo, por ejemplo [{"llave":"valor"}, {"llave":"valor"}, ...], y posteriormente realizar un for tradicional... for ($i = 0; $i < count($arrayJson); $i++)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No sé si hay alguna razón justificada para evitar el uso de `foreach`.

Si quieres otras alternativas, aparte de lo que indica @juan, hay otras alternativas, pero quiero que conste que ninguna es mejor que `foreach`:

En las alternativas 1 a 3 crearemos el array así a partir del JSON:

```
$strJson='
{
 "llave1":"valor1","llave2":"valor2","llave3":"valor3"
}';

$arrayJson=json_decode($strJson);
```

#### 1. Usando `array_walk`:

```
array_walk($arrayJson, function(&$v, $k) { $v = "$k: $v".PHP_EOL; echo $v;});
```

---

#### 2. Con `while` y usando además `list` y `each`

O sea, **dos funciones adicionales**.

```
while (list($k, $v) = each($arrayJson)) {
    echo "$k: $v".PHP_EOL;
}
```

#### 3. Usando `foreach` lo que no quieres precisamente, pero lo mejor

Esto es lo más simple y rápido:

```
foreach ($arrayJson as $k => $v) {
    echo $k . ': ' . $v.PHP_EOL;
}
```

Debe haber una razón muy justificada para no querer usarlo :)

#### 4. Usando `array_map`

En este caso, vamos a construir el array a partir del JSON así:

```
$arrayJson=json_decode($strJson,TRUE);
```

Y usamos `array_map` combinado con `array_keys`. En el callback imprimimos las llaves y los valores:

```
$callback = function ($k, $v) {
    echo "$k: $v".PHP_EOL;
    //return array($k => $k);
  };

array_map( $callback, array_keys($arrayJson), $arrayJson);
```

En los tres códigos la salida es la misma:

**Salida:**

```
llave1: valor1
llave2: valor2
llave3: valor3
```

Comment: Estoy usando un foreach  para hacer la insercion a la base pero no se porque estraña rason me duplica los insert a la base, el el json van instrucciones sql tipo insert, esto es para subir los datos de una aplicacion movil android a un servidor postgresql, de echo es una de tus preguntas como sincronizar datos de sqlite  aun server de BD

Comment: @IgmerRodriguez entonces el problema no es el `foreach`, no cabe duda de que **el problema está en otra parte**, sea que los datos de por sí están repetidos en el JSON, sea que llamas el método de inserción dos veces, etc. De todos modos, la tabla debería tener una restricción `UNIQUE` que evite los registros repetidos. Eso no quita que revises el código hasta dar con el problema que hace que los datos se dupliquen, pero no es por el `foreach` en sí.

Comment: si en eso estoy no se si es postgresql el json lo he revisado muy bien y se que no van duplicados, el unique en la base podria ser pero primero queria ver otras opciones

Comment: si en eso estoy no se si es postgresql el json lo he revisado muy bien y se que no van duplicados, el unique en la base podria ser pero primero queria ver otras opciones

Comment: @IgmerRodriguez la restricción `UNIQUE` impedirá que se inserten duplicados, pero el código debe ser controlado también. Con que se llame dos veces a un método o algo parecido basta para que la inserción se haga o se intente hacer dos veces. Es cuestión de revisar dónde ocurre ese problema. Puede ser cuestión de la petición, que se hace dos veces o quién sabe. Si tienes el código organizado no será difícil encontrar el error. Saludos.

Comment: Lo extraño es que cuando son pocos registros no los duplica solo cuando son mas de 200 inserciones, pero sigo revisando gracias por e apoyo

Comment: @IgmerRodriguez sí es extraño. Aunque dices que el JSON está bien, tratándose de tantos registros, ¿estás seguro de ello?  ¿miraste en el JSON si no hay duplicados, quizá lejos unos de otros, digamos que el elemento 3 del JSON se repite más adelante, en el elemento 312? Yo depuraría también por ahí, ante un duplicado, buscaría ese dato (manualmente) en el JSON para ver si no aparece varias veces.

Comment: si te aseguro que he revisado el json linea por linea y si envio 200 ingresa 400 osea los duplica pero si envio 10 solo ingresa 10, entiendo que el foreach se puede probar con miles de registros sin problema ahora vere si es un problema de posgresql

Comment: @IgmerRodriguez si no encuentras el motivo entonces podrías abrir una nueva pregunta poniendo el código implicado en todo el proceso de toma de datos e inserción.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la función each

```
for($i=0;$i<count($arrayJson);$i++)
    {
        list($key, $val)=each($arrayJson);
        echo $key . ': ' . $val;
    }
```

Comment: la propia documentación de PHP menciona que each es mas lenta que foreach y aparte esta función esta `deprecated` desde PHP 7